# Class '(Anonymous class)' incorrectly extends base class 'T'

Tags: typescript-decorator

Hi I want to implement a class decorator that extends the constructor of the original class; that is my code:

```
 export function Offline<T extends {new (...args:any[]):T}>(constr:T){

 OfflineManagerService.registerService(constr)
 console.log("-- decorator function invoked --");
 return class extends constr{
    constructor(...args:any[]){
       super(...args)
       console.log('decorated')
    }
```

I get this error :

> Class '(Anonymous class)' incorrectly extends base class 'T'.
> '(Anonymous class)' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'new (...args: any[]) => T'

unfortunately I do not know how to fix it